# Creating .NET Core DataProtectionProvider that uses legacy machineKey

Tags: .net-core

I have an application that uses Asp.Net Identity. I need to generate a GRANT-TOKEN for that application in an Azure Function v3. When I've had to do this before in a .NET 4.6 Class Library I created a custom IDataProtector that used System.Web.Security.MachineKey.

I'm struggling to find anything that describes how I can create a DataProtectionProvider with a fixed valiadtionKey and decryptionKey.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone's created a Machine Key DataProtectionProvider [here](https://github.com/daixinkai/AspNetCore.Owin/tree/master/src/DataProtection) and it worked without issue.